# Best plugin to manage ads - needs to substitute different ads at different widths

Tags: wordpress, statistics, advertising

I've recently built a news site with WordPress (in the niche of watches - [timeandtidewatches.com](http://timeandtidewatches.com/)). I'm about to integrate ads on the site. I'd like an ad manager that can handle using a skyscraper in desktop view, dropping to a banner in tablet view, and a wide block for mobile. Currently the site is fully responsive (we don't serve a mobile specific site).

Looking around at the normally recommended plugins they don't seem to do this.

I'd like:

1. Ability to add a new advertisement, and attach different size images to this advertisement that will show on different screen widths.
2. Ability to restrict ads to certain categories or pages.
3. Ability to have a fall-back ad for when no other ad will show.
4. Tracking and stats.
5. I'd rather it loaded the ads only when necessary, rather than loading them all on using something like display:none to hide the inactive ones.

It can be local or run elsewhere, in fact having an install elsewhere that could serve multiple sites would be a bonus long term, but not necessary now.

Comment: The biggest issue I see with this is finding a way to get the screen size and return the desired ad in a timely manner. You also may have issues depending on who you are using for your ads. The way I have does this in the past is to just wrap my adwords code inside a responsive div with some slight CSS edits to adwords

Comment: I'm fine with the individual ads - they will all be created by me and mainly images - it's that I want the have different ads in different positions at different screen widths that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your using something like Bootstrap you can hide div's in certain views. So when someone loads the site you need to actually load 3 ads and only display 1 in their view. If the view changes or they load the site from a different device a different ad is displayed. This doesn't need a plugin to WordPress and is something that you'd set up in your template.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [WP Ad Pro](https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-pro-advertising-system-all-in-one-ad-manager/269693) for this.

- You can specify ad zones *and* banners per device, for example

  [image: per device].
- Ads can be specified per blog category (but not pages)

  [image: per category]
- A default image can be specified for empty adzones

  [image: default image]
- It does statistics

  [image: Publishers stats image]
- Unsure of how it loads inactive ads, but it's full featured so I
  suspect it's pretty intelligent about it